# longitudinal model vs anova

Tags: anova, panel-data

Does anyone know why longitudinal regression models are still able to work when you have a different number of observations for each person (non-balanced design)... but ANOVA models are not able to work as well in this situation?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: I suspect you are thinking of an ANOVA that doesn't properly handle the correlation structure in repeated measurements, so the comparison is not so useful.  More [here](https://fharrell.com/post/re) (see the large table at the bottom).

Comment: e.g. there are mice in a lab ... I have 3 measurements for the first mouse, 5 measurements for the second mouse, etc .... in this case, there are unequal number of measurements for each mouse. longitudinal model here is better than anova?

Comment: does it really make sense to calculate the correlation/variance of individual subjects in longitudinal model when you only have 4-5 observations for each mouse? dont you need more than that?